# jquery index() how to call something by its index

Tags: jquery

I have two divs both containing images. Here is some example code:

```
<div id="one">
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
    <img src="image2.jpg"/>
    <img src="image3.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <img src="otherimage.jpg"/>
    <img src="otherimage2.jpg"/>
    <img src="otherimage3.jpg"/>
</div>
```

I have a hover event on the second set of images so that i get the index of the image that was hovered and store it in a variable called index. So say I hover over the second image in div two my index variable will equal 1. How can i then use this index to do something to the image that is at the same index in div one?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`eq` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('#one img').eq(index).something()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$("#one").find("img").eq(yourindexvar).addClass("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#one').find('img')[index].whatever();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery's nth-child() selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

[Here is an example of it in use.](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/jrrmC/)

```
$('#two img:nth-child(1)').css('border', '5px red solid');
```

***Note:** `nth-child()` isn't 0 based indexing `eq()` is.*